# See what variable triggered If statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

```
$one=$_POST['one'];
$two=$_POST['two'];
$three=$_POST['three'];
$four=$_POST['four'];
$five=$_POST['five'];
$six=$_POST['six'];
$seven=$_POST['seven'];
$eight=$_POST['eight'];
$nine=$_POST['nine'];
$ten=$_POST['ten'];
if ( $one   == "gift" or $two   == "gift" or $three == "gift" or $four  == "gift" or $five  == "gift" or $six   == "gift" or $seven == "gift" or $eight == "gift" or $nine  == "gift" or $ten   == "gift" ) {
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=./gift.php?item=" . ??? . "' />";
}
```

What do I put in the ??? to fill the variable name that triggered the if statement...

Comment: Use an array instead of ten variables.

Comment: Fun fact: OP already has an nice array :)

Comment: ^ a super array in fact ...

Comment: this is pretty backward...  why not use $_POST['GIFT'] = one->ten ?!?!

Comment: I got the answer from @deseze

Comment: $_POST already is an array!!

Comment: Didn't know $_POST was an array super cool!

Comment: lol, but you know to access it like an array?!

Comment: Yes the answer is below by @deseze

Answer (score 7):

```
$key = array_search('gift', $_POST);
if ($key) {
    echo "$key equals 'gift'";
} else {
    echo "nothing equals 'gift'";
}
```